# Ubuntu 11.10 can't play music with Logitech Bluetooth receiver

Tags: 11.10, sound, bluetooth

I'm a very basic Ubuntu 11.10 user and I'm trying to stream music on a *Logitech wireless speaker adapter for bluetooth audio devices*.

I can get to pair the device with my computer, but I can't play music. I also can't find the device on the Sound Settings.

I tried with Blueman, but with the same results. I've seen that this problem was solved before, but I can't make it work in mine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me

I Think you have to install "Bluez" tools first (theres a metapackage) out of synaptic/software center.

Comment: I recommend running "sudo update-manager -d" in terminal. Upgrade to the newest.